magnetic field of stator when load increases in an induction motor
What happens to the magnetic field of the stator when the load increases in an induction motor? I understand that due to the higher torque demanded the speed of the rotor will decrease. So the slip increases due to the increase in the relative speed of the rotor and the magnetic field of the stator. The induced emf in the rotor windings increases and as a result the current too. The magnetic field of the rotor increases but what happens to the back emf induced in the stator by the magnetic field of the rotor? Does it increase? If so what happens to the current of the stator?
